# TFS scheduled build not getting triggered

Tags: tfs, build-definition

We have TFS build definitions that are configured to run every night at 10:00 PM ("Schedule" option and "Build even if nothing changed..." are selected). For some testing, I modified one of them to run at 10:30 AM and was waiting for it to get triggered. But, it did not get triggered.

I googled for it but found that there is a different problem that it gets triggered with some delay and it fixed in TFS 2010. But, our TFS is not 2010.

I am not sure why my scheduled build is not getting triggered.

I checked that my build service is up and running on the build machine and there are no network issues seen.

any help is highly appreciated.

regards,
kvk938

Comment: Can you manually run the build definition?

Comment: @ ds19, yes it gets triggered when I trigger it manually.

Comment: Did you check the Event viewer on TFS AT server on the time when the build definition should be started?

Comment: @ ds 19, unfortunately the TFS server is at a remote location and I do not have access to connect it.

Comment: Which version of tfs do you have then?

Comment: Is the TFS server in a different time zone?

Comment: @MrHinsh, the TFS server version is 2013.

Comment: @ansariwn, yes the TFS server is in a different time zone.